# Box2D Dynamic bodies with masks applied overlapping causes frame-rate drop

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have about six dynamic bodies which have collision masks set so that they do not collide, however when they all overlap on screen for any length of time the frame-rate is dropping noticably. is this to be expected? I presumed that if the mask were set then they would not be checked for collisions and did not think this would happen? none of the bodies have bullet enabled.

I'm running the game on a samsung S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bodies have a lot of fixtures and they are moving around, it might be due to the dynamic tree being restructured frequently. Although this particular group of fixtures may be set to not collide with each other, the tree still gets updated to let them collide with other things in the world. If the fixtures never ever need to collide with *anything* then it would be possible to optimize this by setting their mask bits to zero and not including them in the dynamic tree at all, but I guess this was not done because there is no point having a fixture that never collides with anything.

Comment: thanks. i was using Physics body editor to create the bodies, and was not accounting for large number of fixtures. i have simplified the bodies and it seems to be working much faster.